# Can I strictly evaluate a boolean expression stored as a string in Java?

Tags: java, boolean, eval, beanshell

I would like to be able to evaluate an boolean expression stored as a string, like the following:

```
"hello" == "goodbye" && 100 < 101
```

I know that there are tons of questions like this on SO already, but I'm asking this one because I've tried the most common answer to this question, [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), and it allows for the evaluation of statements like this one

```
"hello" == 100
```

with no trouble at all. Does anyone know of a FOSS parser that throws errors for things like operand mismatch? Or is there a setting in BeanShell that will help me out? I've already tried Interpreter.setStrictJava(true).

For completeness sake, here's the code that I'm using currently:

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.setStrictJava(true);    
String testableCondition = "100 == \"hello\"";
try {
    interpreter.eval("boolean result = ("+ testableCondition + ")");
    System.out.println("result: "+interpreter.get("result"));
    if(interpreter.get("result") == null){
        throw new ValidationFailure("Result was null");
    }
} catch (EvalError e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new ValidationFailure("Eval error while parsing the condition");
}
```

**Edit:**

The code I have currently returns this output

```
result: false
```

without error. What I would like it to do is throw an EvalError or *something* letting me know that there were mismatched operands.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have currently?

Comment: "Does anyone know of a FOSS parser" == off topic question

Answer (score 2):

In Java 6, you can dynamically invoke the compiler, as explained in this article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html

You could use this to dynamically compile your expression into a Java class, which will throw type errors if you try to compare a string to a number.

Comment: That was an awesome link. Unfortunately, I need something that works with java 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [eval project](https://eval.dev.java.net/)

Comment: eval is pretty sweet, but I need a string = functions as well

Answer (score 0):

Use Janino! http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home

Its like eval for java

Answer (score 0):

MVEL would also be useful

http://mvel.codehaus.org/

one line of code to do the evaluation in most cases:

```
Object result = MVEL.eval(expression, rootObj);
```

"rootObj" could be null, but if it's supplied you can refer to properties and methods on it without qualificiation. ie.    "id" or "calculateSomething()".

Answer (score 0):

You can try with http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html if groovy is an option.