# Java - How to write a code that Solve equation inside a String?

Tags: java, string, parsing, math, methods

How to make a string that can solve an equation, for example : if we have

```
String x = "a=3;b=4;c=a*b";
```

it must return `"c=12"` for an answer

Comment: i made a method like this : static String solver(String s) {return "something";} so if the user put some equation inside this method it will return the answer of that math equation, but the problem is how to make the string calculate those equation?, do you know how to do that?

Comment: It don't have any meaning?

Comment: please Provide the code since what you have tried so far,because in Stackoverflow answers will be available for keeping effort developres not the guys trying to just copy the code and execute

Comment: homework? use math libraries for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992071/can-i-strictly-evaluate-a-boolean-expression-stored-as-a-string-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @Emilio yeah my last homework for this smester, the problem is i didn't go to the class in the last week, so i don't understand how to do this, i have a deadline to do this hw until 12 midnight

Comment: @Arief27 go to class it's good for the soul!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. I cannot give you code... I can give you some advice..

1. Split the String based on semicolon (;).
2. For each String in the array (which you got after splitting, except the last one) split it again based on "=".
3. Take the RHS of the split String and parse it as integer.
4. Now parse the last String which you got after splitting the main String based on ";". See what operation is present inside it using contains(). Also check what are the variables involved using contains(). Check the variables int value (which you got after splitting based on "=" and using Integer.parseInt on the RHS part.)
5. Perform the operation based on what the String contains (*,+,-,/) . You could use a switch statement for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a parser suitable for a given grammar (I expect it's smth similar to Java, with basic arithmetics). Or simply run Jython and check results (Jython is Python implementation for JVM, The value of `x` string is suitable for Python grammar). Probably you could parse the string yourself, but frankly I won't suggest you to do this. Basically because a decent parser is complex enough (obviously later you'll need operators priority: 2 + 3*4 == 14, not 20, you will need () and so on). So Python or alike is a fastest solution for a calculator.